# How to use regular expression inside function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using following python script to copy files between windows machines.

```
from subprocess import call

def copy_logs():
    file= '.\pscp.exe -pw test123 C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\interact.* Administrator@1.1.1.1:/'
    call(file)

copy_logs()
```

If I run the above script, I'm getting following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> python .\execute_pscp.py
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\interact.*: No such file or directory

PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>
```

But if i specify filename exactly as "file= '.\pscp.exe -pw test123 C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\interact_python.py  Administrator@1.1.1.1:/'", its working perfectly as shown below.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> python .\execute_pscp.py
interact_python.py        | 0 kB |   0.2 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>
```

But I want to use some regular expression inside the command "interact.*". So that I can copy some particular file/files.

And also I want execute this script every three hours. its there any way in python to achieve this?

Comment: You are just passing arguments to `pscp.exe`. `pscp.exe` has to support that kind of input.

Comment: `call(file, shell=True)`. You are trying to use shell functionality (shell is responsible for expanding asterisk, not launched application) when shell is not launched at all.

Comment: On windows shell does NOT expand asterisk.

Comment: @zvone: it does: "You can use wildcards to transfer multiple files in either direction, like this:

pscp c:\documents\*.doc fred@example.com:docfiles
pscp fred@example.com:source/*.c c:\source"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Those are wildcards, not regular expressions. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: @zvone: mystery solved! nice.

Answer (score 0):

I tried "import os" module as shown below. Its working perfectly.

```
import os

def copy_logs():
    os.system(".\pscp.exe -pw test123 C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\interact_pyth* Administrator@1.1.1.1:/")

copy_logs()
```

Comment: Did you try with `Subprocess.call` ? I bet it works too.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If I use "subprocess.call(file)", its throws "NameError: global name 'subprocess' is not defined" error.

Comment: `import subprocess` first. Also, backslashes are better escaped (or prefixed with raw prefix, or you can have some surprises).

Comment: You are now using wildcard `*` and in the original code, you used regular expression `.*`.